# Force php to load libcurl.so.4 from different location?

Tags: php, curl, centos7, libcurl

is there a posibbility to force php to load libcurl from /usr/lib/ instead /usr/lib64/ on centos 7? The problem is that I compiled a modified version of curl that uses openssl instead NSS and I want this library to be loaded in php.

When just replacing libcurl.so.4 in /usr/lib64/ with my customized libcurl, it works but unfortunately breaks my package manager.

When modifying php.ini it seems to be ignored:

```
extention="/usr/lib/libcurl.so.4"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

LD_PRELOAD was the answer ;)

I simply created a bash script that gets run instead the original php binary. So I build a wrapper and now things are working great.